# Xamarin/Maui app still goes to sleep even though told not to

Tags: android, xamarin, maui

My .Net Maui app, running on Android (API 33), needs to stay running. I had thought that using an Android Foreground Service took care of this, but have now discovered that Android sends the app and its foreground service to sleep after a few minutes. Well, I believe it is sleeping, as the log file that the app should update regularly stops getting updated, and the app "wakes up" and starts logging again if I unlock the phone. If I run the app on a real device and with wireless debugging running, connected to my dev laptop, the app stays awake, but goes to sleep if not debugging.
I have tried 2 approaches and neither is keeping my app running:

1. I told Android to not apply battery optimisations to the app, by going into Settings -> Apps -> My App Name -> Battery -> select Unrestricted
2. I told Android to set my app as a never-sleeping app, by going into Settings -> Battery and device care -> Battery -> Background usage limits -> Never sleeping apps -> add My App Name (NOTE this undoes what was done in step 1)

Is there some other way to keep the app's foreground service running?

Comment: Did you try to keep the screen unlock? As far as I know, when the screen locked the app will be in the pause state.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT, the app needs to always run, even when the screen is locked. For that reason I chose to implement a foreground service in the app, but still it goes to sleep.

Comment: Shouldn't that kind of functionnality be in a background service ? From the Android doc `Only use a foreground service when your app needs to perform a task that is noticeable by the user, even when they're not directly interacting with the app` writting logs doesn't seems like something the user should know about

Comment: @Poulpynator, atm my app is just writing to a log file, but eventually it will be monitoring the accelerometer and will need to display a notification if it detects an impact over a certain threshold.

Comment: Here is some links that may help you : https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.os.powermanager.newwakelock?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13 still I would rethink this, I would personnaly don't like an app that keep my phone constantly awake to maybe send a notification at some point. I think that you can have a background service that wake up your phone only then needed (through wakelock)

Comment: @Poulpynator, thank you. Since posting this question I've done more research and actually just tried using a wake lock via a foreground service; I created another foreground service (ScreenOffService) and a BroadcastReceiver (ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver) that recieves SCREEN_OFF events and, when it does, acquires a WakeLock with the Partial flag; this lets the screen go off and lock. ScreenOffService calls RegisterReceiver(new ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver()). My app seems to stay awake now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since posting this question I've done more research found that creating a [wake lock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock) via a foreground service keeps the app running even when the screen is off.

To do this, I created a foreground service (ScreenOffService, inherited from Android.App.Service).

I also created a BroadcastReceiver (ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver, inherited from Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver) that recieves SCREEN_OFF events and, when it does, acquires an Android.OS.PowerManager.WakeLock with WakeLockFlags.Partial.

ScreenOffService calls its base class's RegisterReceiver(new ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver()).
My app stays awake now.

```xml
AndroidManifest.xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

```cs
    var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(ScreenOffService));
    intent.SetAction(ScreenOffService.ActionStartScreenOffService);
    Android.App.Application.Context.StartForegroundService(intent);


    [Service(Label = nameof(ScreenOffService))]
    [RequiresApi(Api = (int)BuildVersionCodes.R)]
    public class ScreenOffService : Service
    {
        private static readonly string TypeName = typeof(ScreenOffService).FullName;
        public static readonly string ActionStartScreenOffService = TypeName + ".action.START";

        internal const int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345678;
        private const string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "screen_off_service_channel_01";
        private const string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "screen_off_service_channel_name";
        private NotificationManager _notificationManager;

        private bool _isStarted;

        private readonly ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver _screenOffBroadcastReceiver;

        public ScreenOffService()
        {
            _screenOffBroadcastReceiver = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver>();
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            _notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            RegisterScreenOffBroadcastReceiver();
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();

            UnregisterScreenOffBroadcastReceiver();
        }

        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            CreateNotificationChannel(); // Elsewhere we must've prompted user to allow Notifications

            if (intent.Action == ActionStartScreenOffService)
            {
                try
                {
                    StartForeground();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to start Screen On/Off foreground svc: " + ex);
                }
            }

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        private void RegisterScreenOffBroadcastReceiver()
        {
            var filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.AddAction(Intent.ActionScreenOff);
            RegisterReceiver(_screenOffBroadcastReceiver, filter);
        }

        private void UnregisterScreenOffBroadcastReceiver()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_screenOffBroadcastReceiver != null)
                {
                    UnregisterReceiver(_screenOffBroadcastReceiver);
                }
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error while unregistering {nameof(ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver)}. {ex}");
            }
        }

        private void StartForeground()
        {
            if (!_isStarted)
            {
                Notification notification = BuildInitialNotification();
                StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

                _isStarted = true;
            }
        }

        private Notification BuildInitialNotification()
        {
            var intentToShowMainActivity = BuildIntentToShowMainActivity();

            var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name))
                .SetContentText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.screen_off_service_started_notification_text))
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.eip_logo_symbol_yellow) // Android top bar icon and Notification drawer item LHS icon
                .SetLargeIcon(global::Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.eip_logo_yellow)) // Notification drawer item RHS icon
                .SetContentIntent(intentToShowMainActivity)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .Build();

            return notification;
        }

        private PendingIntent BuildIntentToShowMainActivity()
        {
            var mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            mainActivityIntent.SetAction(Constants.ACTION_MAIN_ACTIVITY);
            mainActivityIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
            mainActivityIntent.PutExtra(Constants.SERVICE_STARTED_KEY, true);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, mainActivityIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

            return pendingIntent;
        }

        private void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            NotificationChannel chan = new(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationImportance.Default)
            {
                LightColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 255, 0).ToInt(),
                LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public
            };

            _notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan);
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.eip.MobileApp.ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver", Label = "ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver", Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionScreenOff }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
    public class ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver> _logger;

        private PowerManager.WakeLock _wakeLock;

        public ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver()
        {
            _logger = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<ILogger<ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver>>();
        }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionScreenOff)
            {
                AcquireWakeLock();
            }
        }

        private void AcquireWakeLock()
        {
            _wakeLock?.Release();

            WakeLockFlags wakeFlags = WakeLockFlags.Partial;

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)global::Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(global::Android.Content.Context.PowerService);
            _wakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock(wakeFlags, typeof(ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver).FullName);
            _wakeLock.Acquire();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            _wakeLock?.Release();
        }
    }
```