# Maui/Android Constants

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm new to Maui, I've seen a couple of answers/examples referring to constants:

```
mainActivityIntent.SetAction(Constants.ACTION_MAIN_ACTIVITY);
```

In questions such as [Xamarin/Maui app still goes to sleep even though told not to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75892669/xamarin-maui-app-still-goes-to-sleep-even-though-told-not-to)

So when I try to use the code:

```
[Service(Label = nameof(ScreenOffService))]
[RequiresApi(Api = (int)BuildVersionCodes.R)]
public class ScreenOffService : Service
{
    private static readonly string TypeName = typeof(ScreenOffService).FullName;
    public static readonly string ActionStartScreenOffService = TypeName + ".action.START";

    internal const int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345678;
    private const string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "screen_off_service_channel_01";
    private const string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "screen_off_service_channel_name";
    private NotificationManager _notificationManager;

    private bool _isStarted;

    private readonly ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver _screenOffBroadcastReceiver;

    public ScreenOffService()
    {
        _screenOffBroadcastReceiver = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver>();
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        _notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        RegisterScreenOffBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();

        UnregisterScreenOffBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        CreateNotificationChannel(); // Elsewhere we must've prompted user to allow Notifications

        if (intent.Action == ActionStartScreenOffService)
        {
            try
            {
                StartForeground();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to start Screen On/Off foreground svc: " + ex);
            }
        }

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    private void RegisterScreenOffBroadcastReceiver()
    {
        var filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.AddAction(Intent.ActionScreenOff);
        RegisterReceiver(_screenOffBroadcastReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void UnregisterScreenOffBroadcastReceiver()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_screenOffBroadcastReceiver != null)
            {
                UnregisterReceiver(_screenOffBroadcastReceiver);
            }
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error while unregistering {nameof(ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver)}. {ex}");
        }
    }

    private void StartForeground()
    {
        if (!_isStarted)
        {
            Notification notification = BuildInitialNotification();
            StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

            _isStarted = true;
        }
    }

    private Notification BuildInitialNotification()
    {
        var intentToShowMainActivity = BuildIntentToShowMainActivity();

        var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name))
            .SetContentText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.screen_off_service_started_notification_text))
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.eip_logo_symbol_yellow) // Android top bar icon and Notification drawer item LHS icon
            .SetLargeIcon(global::Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.eip_logo_yellow)) // Notification drawer item RHS icon
            .SetContentIntent(intentToShowMainActivity)
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .Build();

        return notification;
    }

    private PendingIntent BuildIntentToShowMainActivity()
    {
        var mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        mainActivityIntent.SetAction(Constants.ACTION_MAIN_ACTIVITY);
        mainActivityIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
        mainActivityIntent.PutExtra(Constants.SERVICE_STARTED_KEY, true);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, mainActivityIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

        return pendingIntent;
    }

    private void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        NotificationChannel chan = new(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationImportance.Default)
        {
            LightColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 255, 0).ToInt(),
            LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public
        };

        _notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan);
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.eip.MobileApp.ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver", Label = "ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver", Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionScreenOff }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private readonly ILogger<ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver> _logger;

    private PowerManager.WakeLock _wakeLock;

    public ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver()
    {
        _logger = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetService<ILogger<ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver>>();
    }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionScreenOff)
        {
            AcquireWakeLock();
        }
    }

    private void AcquireWakeLock()
    {
        _wakeLock?.Release();

        WakeLockFlags wakeFlags = WakeLockFlags.Partial;

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)global::Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(global::Android.Content.Context.PowerService);
        _wakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock(wakeFlags, typeof(ScreenOffBroadcastReceiver).FullName);
        _wakeLock.Acquire();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        _wakeLock?.Release();
    }
}
```

I get the error 'The name "Constants" does not exist in the current context'. Where would I find these so I can reference them?

Comment: I believe they are user defined.  See https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/main/ApplicationFundamentals/ServiceSamples/ForegroundServiceDemo/Constants.cs