# How to keep CPU active during a foreground service, NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, android, maui

As explained in this question:[How to continue scanning WiFi networks in the background on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77128327/how-to-continue-scanning-wifi-networks-in-the-background-on-android)
I'm creating an app with NET MAUI which has a service in the foreground, which scans nearby wifi networks, saves the results in a list, and if it finds a certain SSID it has to carry out some operations. As explained in this other question: [How to run a service in the Background when the screen is blank, NET MAUI app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227804/how-to-run-a-service-in-the-background-when-the-screen-is-blank-net-maui-app) my app when closed and the device is active, the app works perfectly. When I turn off the screen the service starts working. Now, thanks to the advice I received in the forget question, my app also works with the screen off, BUT only if connected to the charger. Can you tell me why??

```js
 [Service(Name = "com.BackgroudAppTest.DemoServices")]
 public class DemoServices : Service, IServicesTest
 {
     private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;  
     public int numeroUscite;
     private WifiManager wifiManager;
     private ObservableCollection<string> wifiNetworks = new ObservableCollection<string>();

     public override void OnCreate()   
     {
         base.OnCreate(); 
     }
     public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
     [return: GeneratedEnum]
     public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
           
         if (intent.Action == "START_SERVICE")
         {
             wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.WifiService);

             //Mantiene la CPU attiva quando lo schermo viene spento 
             WakeLockFlags wakeFlags = WakeLockFlags.Partial;
             var powerManager = (PowerManager)GetSystemService(PowerService);
             wakeLock = powerManager.NewWakeLock(wakeFlags, typeof(DemoServices).FullName);
             wakeLock.Acquire();

             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("il servizio è iniziato");
             Task.Delay(2000);                
             //ricevo il numero dall utente
              int intValue = intent.GetIntExtra("MyIntValue", -1) -1;
             //ricevo SSID dall utente
             string userString = intent.Extras.GetString("MySsid");

              Task.Run(async () =>
              {
                   while (true)
                   {
                      bool foud = false;
                      var database = new Database();

                      wifiNetworks.Clear();
                      wifiManager.StartScan();
                      await Task.Delay(5000);
                      IList<ScanResult> scanResults = wifiManager.ScanResults;
                      foreach (ScanResult scanResult in scanResults)
                      {
                          wifiNetworks.Add(scanResult.Ssid);
                          if (scanResult.Ssid.Equals(userString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                          {
                              foud = true;
                              break;                                
                          }                       
                      }

                      if (foud)
                      {
                          intValue++;
                          MessItem nuovoGeoItem = new MessItem
                          {
                              Data = DateTime.Now,
                              Descrizione = "Entrato " + intValue
                          };
                          int esito = await database.AggiungiGeoItem(nuovoGeoItem);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          numeroUscite++;
                          MessItem nuovoGeoItem = new MessItem
                          {
                              Data = DateTime.Now,
                              Descrizione = "Uscito " + numeroUscite
                          };
                          int esito = await database.AggiungiGeoItem(nuovoGeoItem);
                      }


                      // Attendi prima di eseguire una nuova scansione
                      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                   }             
              });
             RegisterNotification();  
         }
         //stop servizio
         else if (intent.Action == "STOP_SERVICE")
         {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("il servizio è fermato");
             StopForeground(true);
             StopSelfResult(startId);               
         }
         return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
     }
     
     public void Start()
     {
         Intent startService = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, typeof(DemoServices));
         startService.SetAction("START_SERVICE");
         MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(startService);
     }
     public void Stop()
     {          
         Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.ActivityCurrent, this.Class);
         stopIntent.SetAction("STOP_SERVICE");
         MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.StartService(stopIntent);
     }
     public override void OnDestroy()
     {
         if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.IsHeld)
         {
             wakeLock.Release();
             wakeLock = null;
         }
         base.OnDestroy();
     }
     private void RegisterNotification()
     {
         NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ServicioChannel", "Servizio Scan", NotificationImportance.Max);
         NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)MainActivity.ActivityCurrent.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
         manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
         Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "ServicioChannel")
             .SetContentTitle("Servizo Attivo")
             .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha)
             .SetOngoing(true)
             .Build();

         StartForeground(100, notification);
     }
 }
```

AndroidManifest.xaml

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <service
            android:name=".Services.DemoServices"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />     
    </application>
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_SETUP_WIZARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_STATE_BACKGROUND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_STATE_CACHED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    
</manifest>
```

Comment: Your operation may consume a lot of battery and battery optimization settings might kill the service/app. You may need to disable battery optimization for your app.

Comment: hi thanks for your advice, but I turned off all the power saving or battery optimization settings, of my device (Samsung S21), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: In the past you should add a ```WakeLock``` for such task, but modern Android versions might bring extra limitations on its usage. You have to discover it on your own or look for a help here from person with recent hands-on experience in this part of Android. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

Comment: Follow this it should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/34573169/7462031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different phone manufacturers have different battery optimization policies. According to the [OEM battery optimization IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179644471):

> Samsung continues to run these shady practices by disabling wake-locks and broadcast messages without user or developer consent

So you can try to test the foreground service with the wake-lock on the android emulator not the Samsung device.

In addition, you can refer to this blog about [battery optimization on Samsung](https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung#user-solution) and the part of [how to prevent certain apps from going to sleep or deep sleep, follow the instructions below](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/galaxy-battery/optimization/) in the official document about Samsung Galaxy Battery optimization.